# Angular forms formArrayName directive usage

Tags: angular, forms

The example in Angular official docs show the following code:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div formArrayName="cities">
        <div *ngFor="let city of cities.controls; index as i">
          <input [formControlName]="i">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class NestedFormArray {
  form = new FormGroup({
    cities: new FormArray([
      new FormControl('SF'),
      new FormControl('NY'),
    ]),
  });

  get cities(): FormArray { return this.form.get('cities') as FormArray; }

}
```

I can't understand why we need the formArrayName directive when the code works even without it?

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
        <div *ngFor="let city of cities.controls; index as i">
          <input [formControlName]="i">
        </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
        <div *ngFor="let city of cities.controls; index as i">
          <input [formControlName]="i">
        </div>
 </form>
```

It's not working without FormArrayName for structure like:

```
new FormGroup({
  cities: new FormArray([
    new FormControl('SF'),
    new FormControl('NY'),
  ]),
});
```

`<input [formControlName]="i">` - says how to syncs a FormControl(input) to an existing `<form [formGroup]="form">`.

So it properly work for that structure:

```
new FormArray([
    new FormControl('SF'),
    new FormControl('NY'),
]);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, can't understand what you mean.

Comment: TLDR without FormArrayName it will work for form = FormArray([new FormControl('SF'), new FormControl('NY')])

Comment: Maybe i misunderstand you, check this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3br2x5) pls